# how to add columns to record the comparisons of any two columns in r

Tags: r

I have an data frame as below. I want to compare any two columns and add one column for recording the result for each comparison. For example, to compare column3 and column5, if equal or column3="--" or column5="--", then put 0 in the new column (named pop1), otherwise, put integer 1. if I want to do other comparisons, it will repeat the same procedures. the result of the first comparison using my code is not right. I greatly appreciate any helps this kind of comparisons and add a loop for multiple times of comparisons to add new column names and values in an efficient way.

```
f=3
m=5
ifelse(
       (df[,f] == df[,m] | df[,f] == "--" | df[,m] == "--"),
       df$pop1 <- 0,
       df$pop1 <- 1
      )


   line1 line2 line3 line4 line5 line6 line7
1     TT    TT    CC    TT    TT    CC    TT
2     CC    AA    AA    AA    CC    AA    AA
3     CC    TT    CC    TT    CC    CC    CC
4     TT    GG    TT    GG    GG    GG    GG
5     CC    CC    TT    CC    TT    CC    CC
6     GG    --    AA    GG    GG    GG    GG
7     AA    GG    GG    GG    --    GG    GG
8     AA    AA    CC    CC    AA    AA    AA
9     TT    CC    TT    CC    TT    CC    TT
10    CC    AA    CC    AA    CC    AA    AA
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare the genotypes per row between columns or an entire column to another entire column? What are you trying to get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a column value based on values in another column in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256828/how-to-set-a-column-value-based-on-values-in-another-column-in-r)

Comment: Just read the post provided by hrbrmstr. I like the solution by fileunderwater. That's basically what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all the comparisons in one hit using `combn`:

Recreate your data:

```
df <- structure(list(line1 = c("TT", "CC", "CC", "TT", "CC", "GG", "AA", "AA", "TT", "CC"), line2 = c("TT", "AA", "TT", "GG", "CC", "--", "GG", "AA", "CC", "AA"), line3 = c("CC", "AA", "CC", "TT", "TT", "AA", "GG", "CC", "TT", "CC"), line4 = c("TT", "AA", "TT", "GG", "CC", "GG", "GG", "CC", "CC", "AA"), line5 = c("TT", "CC", "CC", "GG", "TT", "GG", "--", "AA", "TT", "CC"), line6 = c("CC", "AA", "CC", "GG", "CC", "GG", "GG", "AA", "CC", "AA"), line7 = c("TT", "AA", "CC", "GG", "CC", "GG", "GG", "AA", "TT", "AA")), .Names = c("line1", "line2", "line3", "line4", "line5", "line6", "line7"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Then use:

```
combn(ncol(df),2)
```

which will generate all the combinations two at a time, like:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] ...
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2 ...
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    3 ...
```

You can pass a function to `combn` though to do it all in one step:

```
out <- combn(
  ncol(df),2,
  FUN=function(x) {
    as.numeric(!(df[x[1]] == df[x[2]] | df[x[1]] == "--" | df[x[2]] == "--"))
  }
)
```

And add some nice column names for reference:

```
colnames(out) <- combn(ncol(df),2, FUN=function(x) paste0("from",x[1],"to",x[2]))


#      from1to2 from1to3 from1to4 from1to5 from1to6 from1to7 from2to3 ...
# [1,]        0        1        0        0        1        0        1 ...
# [2,]        1        1        1        0        1        1        0 ...
# [3,]        1        0        1        0        0        0        1 ...
# [4,]        1        0        1        1        1        1        1 ...
# [5,]        0        1        0        1        0        0        1 ...
# [6,]        0        1        0        0        0        0        0 ...
# [7,]        1        1        1        0        1        1        0 ...
# [8,]        0        1        1        0        0        0        1 ...
# [9,]        1        0        1        0        1        0        1 ...
#[10,]        1        0        1        0        1        1        1 ...
```

Comment: +1, but it would be nice to also paste together some names to easily see which column refers to which combination.

Comment: @thelatemail I can subset what I want from the all combinations. Great! But if I have more than 20 columns that would create a big table and difficult to know the each new column corresponds which combination of original two columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this, your ifelse syntax is not quite right:

```
f=3
m=5
df_pop1 <- ifelse(
   (df[,f] == df[,m] | df[,f] == "--" | df[,m] == "--"),
   0,
   1
  )
```